# Usar Forms Authentication em uma aplicação ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-core, forms-authentication

Estou migrando um site **ASP.NET Web Forms** (.NET Framework 4.7) para **ASP.NET Core** (porém ainda usando o .NET 4.7 como "target framework") - o objetivo é usar Razor Pages, injeção de dependência e outros recursos presentes no Core e ao mesmo tempo manter uma compatibilidade mais "transparente" com bibliotecas existentes do .NET Framework (próprias e de terceiros).

Minha dúvida é em relação a recursos web específicos do *ASP.NET Full* como **Forms Authentication**, tentei simplesmente adicionar um arquivo *web.config* e os dados padrões de configuração:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="/Conta/Login" defaultUrl="/PaginaInicial" (...) />
</authentication>
```

Mas um um simples `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` já retorna um erro já que as configurações do web.config aparentemente não são carregadas - o `FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl` por exemplo está com o valor padrão.

> Não tem como usar **FormsAuthentication** no ASP.NET Core mesmo
>   configurando o **Target Framework para NET47** ?

Qual seria a alternativa neste caso? Existe um recurso de autenticação simples parecido no Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabei respondendo minhas próprias dúvidas:

> Não tem como usar FormsAuthentication no ASP.NET Core mesmo
>   configurando o Target Framework para NET47 ?

**Não**, usando diretamente a classe FormsAuthentication não. Mas basta configurar manualmente, segue exemplo de como ficou minha configuração:

No projeto, certificar que as bibliotecas a seguir estão referênciadas (método mais fácil é editar o csproj):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.1.1" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

No Startup.cs, modificar:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //(...)

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(opt =>
            {
                opt.LoginPath = new PathString("/Conta/Login");
                opt.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Conta/Logout");
                opt.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Erros/AcessoNegado");
                opt.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
                {
                    Name = ".NomeCookie",
                    Expiration = new System.TimeSpan(0, 120, 0),
                    //Se tiver um domínio...
                    //Domain = ".site.com.br",
                };
            });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //(...)

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        //(...)                            

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Com isso é só usar o atributo `[Authorize]` em uma Page/Action que seja necessário autenticação e em outra Page/Action de Login implementar a lógica de autenticação, exemplo:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    (...)

   //Sua rotina de autenticação ... 
   var user = await AuthenticateUser(Input.Email, Input.Password);
   if (user == null)
   {
       ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
       return Page();
   }

   //Defina pelo menos um conjunto de claims...
   var claims = new List<Claim>
   {
       //Atributos do usuário ...
       new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
       new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
       new Claim("Nome", user.FullName),                    
   };

   var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

   var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
   {
       IsPersistent = true               
   };

   //Loga de fato
   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
         CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
         new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
         authProperties
   );

   //Redireciona para a url desejada...
   return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```